# ML-Agents release numbers

Tags: unity-game-engine, ml-agent

I'm totally confused about the release numbering Unity is using. Looking at GitHub, I see that the latest release is referred to as 'Release 17' yet the version numbers when looking at things in Package Manager look like 1.08.

Is Release 17 the same as 1.08? Could someone clarify that.

Also, I downloaded Release 17 and installed it by referencing the package.json file however, Unity show it up as 2.0.0

I hope you guys can help.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on Unitys docs about [`Versioning`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-semver.html) I would guess that the overall count of releases is 17, meaning there have been 17 public releases of the package. There is usually a change log that you can find using the package manager that goes into a little more depth for each version. I would guess that the github has more versions than the package manager as the versions released on the package manager are most likely more stable and not just hot fixes.

To summarize, they've had 17 releases, some could have been before version 1.0.0 and you mentioned that 17 is 2.0.0. It could be that 2.0.0 is not stable yet which is why you need to download it from Github to have it in the package manager. Anything prior to the first digit is a patch release version increase. So with 1.0.8, it means they're on major release 1 on patch version 8. The other reason 2.0.0 might not appear in your package manager is due to being on a non verified version of Unity for this package version or not viewing unreleased packages. It could be 2.0.0 works, but is not verified by Unity yet on your Unity version.

Comment: thank you for the response. Your explanation is what I was suspecting. It would be easier to stick with either release numbers or version.patch. On a side note, It's funny that someone voted down question. Again, thank you for taking the time to respond.